# Field modifyDate is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0

Tags: c#, debugging, compiler-warnings

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting this warning? I've tested the code and it works, I get the value that I should be getting in there. Is this a false warning or is there something I'm missing?

```
[DataMember(Name = "modifyDate")]        
private long modifyDate;

public DateTime lastModified 
{
    get { return DateTimeConverter.FromUnixTime(modifyDate); }
}
```

Comment: Well what are you expecting to *set* the value? Is it being set by reflection, perhaps? (Note that your property name should start with a capital letter to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: I'm using a DataContractJsonSerializer. I'm new to C#, have to say the naming conventions are annoying me. I'd rather start every variable with a capital letter and camel case.

Comment: Right - so that's what's setting the value, and you could disable the warning and add an explanatory comment.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I would do that? So you agree then that it's a false warning?

Comment: Search for #pragma warning disable

Comment: Thanks, I suppressed it with the following. I'm still surprised at the warning though and haven't seen anyone else saying they get one when using a private field as a DataMember. 
#pragma warning disable 0649
#pragma warning restore 0649

Comment: Well I'd expect most uses to also supply another way of setting it, such as a constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a compiler warning, which means the compiler cannot find any code at *compile time* that would assign a value. However, it is still possible that a value is assigned at *runtime*. In your case, that's done by `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

If you know that, you can disable the warning by writing

```
#pragma warning disable 0649
```

before the affected line of code and

```
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

after the line of code.

Usually you should also add a comment why you're using that pragma instruction, e.g.

```
// This field is assigned to by JSON deserialization
```

Comment: Great answer. This both explains why I get the warning and how to prevent it. Thanks.